# Why heder('Location:index')not working but window.location.href='index.php' is working?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the Index file like this

```
<?php
include('file1.php');
include('file2.php');
?>
```

in file1.php I am having the code like below.

```
<?php
echo "hai";
?>
```

I am trying to redirect the page by using `header('Location:index.php')`.It throws an error something like the output already started.I know for header if we give the echo statement it throws an error.In this situation I am trying to redirect by using Javascript `window.location.href='index.php'` .It gives me the expected output and there is no error.Why?.

Comment: Where are you using `header('Location: index.php');`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP header command is sending an instruction to the response stream that the browser will interpret as a redirect to a new location. But, by its nature, you can only send a header of any kind before you has started sending content. In your example, you send the content "hai" then tried to send the header.

Now your javascript is executed in the broswer by the javascript engine. As such, the window.location is telling the javascript engine to make the browser request a new page. This is independent of any information contained within the http stream (in theory, the location could be something other than http such as ftp or a mailto).

Comment: As a side note, it's a good practive not to write the trailing ?> in your php files so that no unfortunate space or line break prevent a header to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ob_start();` at the beginning of your PHP file. This will turn on output buffering, collecting all the output generated by your script and waiting til the end of execution before "flushing" the output to the browser.  You can force a flush using `ob_end_flush();`

More info: https://www.php.net/ob_start

Comment: If chosing this option though, do so very carefully. There is a reason that websites do not usually buffer by default. Buffering and flushing increases the memory requirements for your website to accomodate all the extra data that it has to temporarily store rather than just write directly to the output stream. Depending on traffic levels and the complexity of your output, this can take a needless toll on your server.